# Keeps printing white window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wrote these methods of this very simple program (I'm trying to figure out how JFrame works):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {
    private int larg = 512;
    private int lung = 512;

    public Display() {
        setSize(larg, lung);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics gr) {
        Color color = new Color(100, 200, 0);
        gr.setColor(color);
        gr.fillRect(0, 0, larg, lung);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display();
    }
}
```

but they keep printing a white window and not a (100, 200, 0) window, why is that?

Comment: [mcve] or it didn't happent

Comment: The program is very basic, I'm learning how to use JFrame,... if you desire I post all the code

Comment: It's basic but somehow it's wrong, and I'm not sure how to tell. What calls `draw(...)` by the way? Is it being called from within a painting method somewhere?

Comment: updated the source @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I think you want to override `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK you're creating your own painting method, draw, and are assuming that somehow it's magically going to get called. This is not going to happen and is not how Swing graphics works. Google and go through the tutorials, but if you do, you'll see that you need to override a true painting method, one present within the parent component (`paint` for JFrame, `paintComponent` for JPanel for example), and you have to *make **sure*** that you override the method correctly, usually by using the `@Override` annotation or it won't work.

The tutorials will also tell you not to draw directly within the JFrame anyway but rather in the paintComponent override of a JPanel.

Moral of the story: avoid guessing how coding works, but instead go to the primary sources, here the tutorials, to see how to do it right.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;    
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyDraw extends JPanel {

    private static final Color RECT_COLOR = new Color(100, 200, 0);
    private int larg;
    private int lung;

    public MyDraw(int larg, int lung) {
        this.larg = larg;
        this.lung = lung;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, larg, lung);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(larg, lung);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyDraw");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int larg = 512;
        int lung = 512;
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyDraw(larg, lung));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Swing Painting tutorials: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: @dulindraxe: see edit and [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)